# Создание движка сайта на angularjs+php

Tags: php, angularjs

Добрый день!

Разумным ли будет создание движка сайта на использовании связки angularjs+php? Php будет выступать серверной частью. При этом форматом обмена данными между angular и php будет выступать json.
Сайт должен быть простым (используется ограниченным количеством лиц) и важны только следующие функции:
1. Получение количества и наименований элементов панели навигации.
2. Загрузка контента страниц.

Вообще, не составляет труда написать все это, используя лишь php, но начал изучать angularjs и хочется опробовать его работу в связке с php. Но сомневаюсь, не усложняю ли я структуру.

Comment: Да лучше взять любой фреймворк и на нем сделать, а не брать чистый php. В принципе, если хочется, ничего не мешает и прибиндить туда ангуляр. Правда, зачем он там? JS для такого сайта - минимален.

P.S. Если не особо важен интерфейс, такой функционал проще реализовать поверх Wordpress, ModX или Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, что сущетсвуют условия, препятствующие совместному использованию.

С тем же успехом вы можете спрашивать: "На чем мне писать фронт, на голом JS или взять Angular?" Т.е. к PHP не имеет никакого отношения. Самый главный аргумент - это ответ на вопрос, является ли ваше приложение Single Page. Если да, то без Angular-like фреймворка вам не обойтись. Если, конечно, вы не решили пополнить их зоопарк еще одним питомцем?

> Php будет выступать серверной частью.

А как PHP может использоваться на клиенте?

> Получение количества и наименований элементов панели навигации.

Какое отношение это имеет к фронту?

> Загрузка контента страниц.

Соответствеено, если ваши пользователи мечтают прыгать с вкладки на вкладку и сохранять невразумительные адреса из омнибокса, то Angular не нужен.

В любом случае, не проще ли взять готовый движок и "заценить" все прелести из коробки?

Больше тут [Why do many websites use AngularJS for a frontend and PHP as a backend?](http://www.quora.com/Why-do-many-websites-use-AngularJS-for-a-frontend-and-PHP-as-a-backend) и тут [ru.wikipedia/AngularJS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS)